# NodeJS forward image from request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So I have a nodeJS request to an API that generates a chart png.

I want to render that image onto an HTML page, along with some other information, all stored inside a JSON.

```js
const request = require('request');
const http = require("http");

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/download') {
        let options = {'method': 'POST','url': 'https://quickchart.io/chart', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
            body: JSON.stringify({ "c": { "type": "radar", "data": { "labels": ["Joy", "Tentative", "Analytical", "Confident", "Sadness", "Fear", "Anger"], "datasets": [{ "label": "texts", "data": [16.712958999999998, 13.837568999999998, 22.676837000000006, 7.1366060000000004, 7.050827, 0.959514, 1.071042] }] } } })
        };
        request(options, (error, req , image) => {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            
            //i need a JSON with some data on the frontend, this is just a mockup
            var important_data = {
                url     : 'https://quickchart.io/chart',
                //encode the image to add it inside a JSON
                image   : new Buffer(image).toString('base64')
            }

            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end(JSON.stringify(important_data));

        });
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT, () => { console.log('server running !') })
```

Everything seems to be good so far, the image seems to be encoded with this base64 string `RXJyb3I6IGNvdWxkIG5vdCBoYW5kbGUgdGhlIHJlcXVlc3QK` however when I try to render the image on the front end, it does not work.

I found this that tells how to display a base64 image on an HTML page, but for this generated string, it does not work, for some reason.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,RXJyb3I6IGNvdWxkIG5vdCBoYW5kbGUgdGhlIHJlcXVlc3QK" alt="chart" />
```

I also find it odd that my base64 image has such a short string.
Did I encode the image wrong?

Edit: One of the conditions for the assignment I received, is that I cannot use any external libraries aside from  `request`.

As sending a base64 image inside a JSON may not be efficient, it is the only way I found to do it from a bit of research.
I am open to any ideas, as long as it does not involve, external nodejs libraries.

Comment: The 2nd argument to the `request()` callback is NOT your image data.  The image data would be the third argument (which you aren't passing).  Also, the `request()` library has been deprecated as is no longer recommended for new code.  You can see a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

Comment: Also, it's not very efficient to send images as base64 encoding.  It would be better to just stream the image directly which is also something the `got()` library can do for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited the callback function.
About sending the image, inefficient as it may be I need to do it, as the conditions for the assignment I received require me to as I am not allowed to use any external libraries aside from 'request' for this.

Comment: And, what is your result now that you are using the proper argument?

Comment: We can't exactly offer to best way to meet the needs of the assignment, when you haven't even included the rules and objectives of the assignment.  You can mention to your professor that for future classes he should probably recommend something different than `request()` since it has been deprecated and thus isn't really something students should spend time learning or be encouraged to use.

Comment: I'll do so, also I have edited the question, mentioning about this condition.

Comment: @jfriend, in my code, I use the proper argument.
What I have written in the question is a simplified version of what I have.
I just forgot to add the third parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228975/discussion-between-ionut-eugen-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Well, something as short as `RXJyb3I6IGNvdWxkIG5vdCBoYW5kbGUgdGhlIHJlcXVlc3QK` is not likely a valid image.  So, you have to follow the steps of the data and see where things go wrong.